# Material-Ui TextField not affected with the RTL direction

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-Ui in my React Project !

i followed the steps in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#opting-out-of-rtl-transformation) to allow RTL in my project and all work fine !

except the TextField Component

**LTR DIRECTION :**

[image]

**RTL DIRECTION**

[image]

**Like you see ! the problem is with the label still in left ( the input text work fine )**

> App.js file

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


//i18n
import {withTranslation} from "react-i18next";
import './i18n';

//jss
import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

 // Configure JSS
 const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });




  function App(props) {

      // initialize Language
      const {  i18n } = props;
      const [ prefLang, setPrefLang] = useState(i18n.language);
      let theme =createMuiTheme({
        palette : {
            primary : {
                main : '#ed5ac0',
            },

        },
        typography : {
            fontFamily : "lalezar, cursive",
            h3 : {
                fontSize : 1.4,
            },
            h4 : {
                fontSize : 1.5
            },
            fontAwseomeSize : {
                xs : "14px",
                sm : "14px",
                md : "16px"
            },
            responsiveFont : {
                xs : "20px",
                sm : "12.5px",
                md : "14px"
            },
            highLight : {
                md : "25px"
            },
            subHighLight : {
                md : "18px"
            }
        },

    }
);



return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <LangContext.Provider
                value ={{
                    prefLang,
                    setPrefLang
                }}
            >
                <CssBaseline/>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
                        <Grid dir={(prefLang === "ar") ? "rtl" : "ltr"}>
                            {/*<AppHeader/>*/}


                            <ContentRouter/>


                        </Grid>
                    </StylesProvider>
                </ThemeProvider>


            </LangContext.Provider>

          </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }

   export default withTranslation()(App);
```

**My Form Component**

```
const LoginForm = () => {

 return (
    <>
        <Backdrop style={{ zIndex : 999 , color : theme.palette.primary.main}} open={backdrop} >
            <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
        </Backdrop>
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} style={{width: "100%", marginTop: "20px"}}>

            { userNotFound ? <Alert style={{marginBottom : "20px"}} variant="outlined" severity="error">
                This is an error alert — check it out!
            </Alert> : null}
            <TextField
                id="identifier"
                name="identifier"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.identifier}
                label={t('formIdentifier')}
                fullWidth
            />
            {formik.touched.identifier && formik.errors.identifier ?
                (
                    <Alert style={{ marginTop :"10px"}} variant="outlined" severity="error">{formik.errors.identifier}</Alert>

                ) : null}
            <TextField
                style={{marginTop: "50px"}}
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.password}
                label={t('formPassword')}
                fullWidth
            />
            {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password ?
                (
                    <Alert style={{ marginTop :"10px"}} variant="outlined" severity="error">{formik.errors.password}</Alert>

                ) : null}
            <Button type="submit" color="primary">{t('login')}</Button>
        </form>
    </>
     );
  };
```

> My Theme.js File

```
import createMuiTheme from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";

let theme =createMuiTheme({

    direction : 'rtl',
    palette : {
        primary : {
            main : '#ed5ac0',
        },

    },
    typography : {
        fontFamily : "Merienda One, sans-serif",
        h3 : {
            fontSize : 1.4,
        },
        h4 : {
            fontSize : 1.5
        },
        fontAwseomeSize : {
            xs : "14px",
            sm : "14px",
            md : "16px"
        },
        responsiveFont : {
            xs : "20px",
            sm : "12.5px",
            md : "14px"
        },
        highLight : {
            md : "40px"
        }
    },

}
```

);

export default theme;

**Any suggestion to make the label RTL ?**

Comment: It doesn't look like you are setting `direction: 'rtl'` in your theme.

Comment: You should also put the `StylesProvider` element at the top (i.e. around `BrowserRouter`) -- it should definitely be around any other Material-UI elements such as `CssBaseline`; otherwise you will be leveraging two different `jss` instances.

Comment: Hello Ryan , so if i unterstand i have to  move the  `stylesProvider` element arround o`BrowserRouter` and add `direction: 'rtl'` to my theme.js file ? i do like you suggest but nothing nothing happened , if u want you can reply the question with the changes i must made

Comment: Also, are you setting `dir="rtl"` on the `<body>` element?

Comment: done i edit the question

Comment: the proble is only with the `TextField` component , all other component work fine for me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [documentation](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/) contains four steps for rtl support:

1. Set the `dir` attribute on the `body` element.

In my examples below, this is handled by the following:

```
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute("dir", isRtl ? "rtl" : "ltr");
  }, [isRtl]);
```

2. Set the `direction` in the theme.

In my examples below, I am toggling between two themes:

```
const ltrTheme = createTheme({ direction: "ltr" });
const rtlTheme = createTheme({ direction: "rtl" });
...
<ThemeProvider theme={isRtl ? rtlTheme : ltrTheme}>
...
</ThemeProvider>
```

3. Install the rtl plugin.

   - For v4 (using JSS), this means installing `jss-rtl`.
   - For v5 (using Emotion), this means installing `stylis-plugin-rtl`.
4. Load the rtl plugin.

Below is a v4 example showing how to load the rtl plugin for JSS (v5 example further down).

For performance reasons it is important to avoid re-rendering `StylesProvider`, so this should not be in a component with state that can change and therefore trigger a re-render. In my own app, I have the `StylesProvider` element in my `index.js` file as the first element inside the call to react-dom `render`.

```
import rtl from "jss-rtl";
import {
  StylesProvider,
  jssPreset
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// Configure JSS
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <AppContent />
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

The example below includes a `TextField` and you can see that the label's position toggles correctly.

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "jss";
import rtl from "jss-rtl";
import {
  StylesProvider,
  jssPreset,
  ThemeProvider,
  createTheme
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

// Configure JSS
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });

const ltrTheme = createTheme({ direction: "ltr" });
const rtlTheme = createTheme({ direction: "rtl" });

function AppContent() {
  const [isRtl, setIsRtl] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("initial value");
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute("dir", isRtl ? "rtl" : "ltr");
  }, [isRtl]);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={isRtl ? rtlTheme : ltrTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Box m={2}>
        <TextField
          variant="outlined"
          value={value}
          onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
          label={isRtl ? "بريد الكتروني او هاتف" : "Email or Phone"}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        Current Direction: {isRtl ? "rtl" : "ltr"}
        <br />
        <Button onClick={() => setIsRtl(!isRtl)}>Toggle direction</Button>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      <AppContent />
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit rtl example]

Below is an equivalent example for v5 using Emotion.

```
import React from "react";
import rtlPlugin from "stylis-plugin-rtl";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { prefixer } from "stylis";

const cacheLtr = createCache({
  key: "muiltr"
});

const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: "muirtl",
  // prefixer is the only stylis plugin by default, so when
  // overriding the plugins you need to include it explicitly
  // if you want to retain the auto-prefixing behavior.
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin]
});

const ltrTheme = createTheme({ direction: "ltr" });
const rtlTheme = createTheme({ direction: "rtl" });

export default function App() {
  const [isRtl, setIsRtl] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("initial value");
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute("dir", isRtl ? "rtl" : "ltr");
  }, [isRtl]);
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={isRtl ? cacheRtl : cacheLtr}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={isRtl ? rtlTheme : ltrTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box m={2}>
          <TextField
            value={value}
            onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
            label={isRtl ? "بريد الكتروني او هاتف" : "Email or Phone"}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          Current Direction: {isRtl ? "rtl" : "ltr"}
          <br />
          <Button onClick={() => setIsRtl(!isRtl)}>Toggle direction</Button>
        </Box>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit rtl example]

In addition, I have a later answer that discusses flipping icons: [material-ui icons won't flip when I change to RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64307165/material-ui-icons-wont-flip-when-i-change-to-rtl/64307950#64307950).

Comment: Thank you Sir , i missed the first step

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you I was stuck with this problem for 3 days, thank you again.

Comment: in sandbox its okay but when i copy the above code, still i have the label problem and also textfield does not move right and left :|

Comment: Heck that's a lot of work compared to just doing "direction: rtl" in plain HTML or CSS. Also I've done steps 1 and 2 and it doesn't suffice even when I don't want to use styled components at all. This seems like something MUI may want to fix some time.

Answer (score 3):

### RTL for specific components, and not the whole app:

[MUI rtl documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/right-to-left/#main-content) and the accepted answer pertain to the entire application.

If you want just a few components here and there, all you need to do is create a simple wrapper component, and children will have rtl. No need for a theme provider.

Just be sure to wrap the `children` with a `<div dir="rtl">`.

**Wrapper Component**:

```
import React from 'react';
import rtlPlugin from "stylis-plugin-rtl";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { prefixer } from 'stylis'


const cacheRtl = createCache({
    key: "muirtl",
    stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin]
});

const RtlProvider = ({ children }) => {

    return (
        <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
            <div dir="rtl">
                {children}
            </div>
        </CacheProvider>
    );
};

export default RtlProvider;
```

**Simple Implementation**

```
return (
  <RtlProvider>
      <TextField label="my label"/>
  </RtlProvider>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I've found to set this for specific component is to add it via native JS after component is rendered.

First I created a ref to the input element:

```
const inputRef = createRef() 
<TextField inputRef={inputRef} />
```

Then added a useEffect hook to perform once on each render:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    if(inputRef) 
        inputRef.current.dir = 'auto' 
}, [])
```

Not the most beautiful code, but it sure works

Answer (score 0):

Making CacheProvider tag as a youngest parent for your content, such like below:

```
<ThemeProvider>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <BaseOptionChartStyle />
      <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>    
      <Router />
    </CacheProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

*note:
(Router) includes the various textFields

Answer (score -2):

apart from theme and jss-rtl and stuff that [Ryan Cogswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495930/ryan-cogswell) said, there's one tiny problem that i found no where after days of searching (just 3-4 days actualy :)).
and that is the import statement.

make sure youre import statement is like the following:

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";   //true
```

if youre import statement is like following, none of those theming and jss stuff works:

```
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";   //false
```