# What the notched property is supposed to do in Material-UI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI for a project and I'm going through their API.

However, I don't understand the `notched` property in the [OutlineInput](https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/) Component

```js
<FormControl variant='outlined'>
  <OutlinedInput notched={false} />
</FormControl>
```

Switching the `notched` property from false to true doesn't change anything visually.

Also, as I'm not a native English speaker, I quite don't understand what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `notched` property only has a visible effect in combination with the `labelWidth` property. When `notched` is true, it leaves a gap in the outline where the label is placed when the label's `shrink` property is `true`. Generally there is no need to use the `notched`, `labelWidth`, or `shrink` properties explicitly. If you use `TextField` (instead of the lower-level `OutlinedInput`) all of these details are handled automatically.

Here's an example demonstrating this:

```
import React from "react";
import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OutlinedInput notched={false} labelWidth={100} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <OutlinedInput notched={true} labelWidth={100} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <TextField variant="outlined" label="The Label" value="The Value" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{ notched: false }}
        label="The Label"
        value="The Value"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit OutlinedInput notched]

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. Setting notched to false removes the extra space on top of the upper outline. This space is used by the label to center vertically with the upper outline when it shrink

Comment: @eakl It doesn't deal with space "on top" of the upper outline. Setting `notched` to true creates a space in the middle of the outline so that there isn't a line going through the label text. I've added one more example to the sandbox that demonstrates what it looks like if you force `notched` to be `false` when it should be `true`.

Comment: It is like having a white space surrounding the label with a higher z-index than the outline

Comment: Yes, the notch is an absolute-positioned element which covers the border with a size slightly bigger than the label, and then the label has a z-index higher than the notch so that it appears on top. The notch itself doesn't need a z-index value since it is a descendant of the element providing the outline, so it appears on top of the outline by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ryan. It’s a lot clearer :)

Comment: It is sometimes necessary to implement your own notch, especially in RTL direction, because its positioning seems to be hard-coded -- unless I am missing a possibility which I would like advice upon! :)

Comment: @Gabriel The notch works just fine in RTL: https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-example-b115r. That sandbox is a modified version of the sandbox in my RTL-related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799638/material-ui-textfield-not-affected-with-the-rtl-direction/62802353#62802353. These examples are both v4. If I have time later today, I'll create an RTL example for v5.

Comment: @Gabriel Not sure if you're using v4 or v5, but I've added a v5 example to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799638/material-ui-textfield-not-affected-with-the-rtl-direction/62802353#62802353.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ryan. I do work with v5. As your examples say, one must rely on an RTL-support plugin for it to work, which is more or less what I was meaning: out of the box, the notch for RTL will display wrongly (without a plugin or your own custom code/css fulfilling a similar role as someone else's plugin).

Comment: Nice answer. Button I dont think it works anymore. There isn't any labelWidth prop in the [v5.8.2 documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/outlined-input/). Would appreciate if you could update your answer

Answer (score 1):

[Ryan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65309199/18620006) is very good. However it is slightly different in the [current version of v5 docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/outlined-input/). The `labelWidth` prop is no longer supported. As of now there are two steps involved in the notch process.

The workflow that requires a `notched` prop is little bit contrived, as it would mean that there will be a notch or whitespace at the top of your input box, no matter what the situation is. Nevertheless, if that is your requirement, you need to specify both `notched={true}`(or simply `notched`), as well as `label="Whatever your label text is"`. The component will provide a notch that is the width of the text you provided in the `label` prop.

```
<OutlinedInput notched={true} id="test" label="HI" />
```

If you do not explicitly mention notched, the behaviour is that the notch will be visible when the input is focused. It will not persist when you click away, regardless of whether there is text content in the input box.

A more common workflow involves actually providing a label for the input component. This is something you would do when making your own custom components from MUI components. Here you do not need to specify the notched prop, as the default behaviour will do the trick. However you do need to specify a separate `InputLabel` component, and wrap both in a `FormControl`, for the notch to be occupied by the required label.

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>Label Text</InputLabel>
  <OutlinedInput label="Label Text" />
</FormControl>
```

The label will work with the code above. However it is recommended to provide a `for` and `id` attribute to help with screen readers.

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="test" id="testlabel">
    Label Text
  </InputLabel>
  <OutlinedInput id="test" label="Label Text" />
</FormControl>
```