# Understanding Material UI 5 in React: ThemeProvider vs StyledEngineProvider vs @emotion CacheProvider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

Kind of a beginner's question - I try to get a deeper understanding of the above components, and about there differences. These is how far I got, maybe it can illustrate my confusion a bit:

- [`ThemeProvider`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming): From my tests, it provides a `Palette` with my style settings for MUI components. N/c where it gets accessed, but I figure MUI components to that implicitely at some point. At least the according `Theme` is made available in all kind of hooks as well as in `createTheme` in `@mui/material/styles`, so I figure this is the one component I understand the most.
- [`StyledEngineProvider`](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/styled-engine): According the documentation, it is there for "generating CSS styles for MUI components". What exactly is the difference to `ThemeProvider`? I've noticed that it must be a child of the `ThemeProvider` component and not the otherway around, or my `Palette` won't apply. Most guides call it with the property `injectFirst` - I figure this way the css data will be put at the start of html's `head`. So is it there to *inject* css data into the html? I seem to need it when using `tss-react` though.
- [`CacheProvider`](https://emotion.sh/docs/cache-provider) from `@emotion/react`: Not sure what's actually cached and I didn't find any example where it's accessed/used in custom code. The documentation here is rather sparse as well, but it tells me to replace `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>` with it. So it seems to expect `injectFirst` to be set whatsoever, and it seems to work more or less as drop-in replacement of `StyledEngineProvider`. I noticed it has a property `prepend` which I suspect to have a similar effect as `injectFirst`. Then, there is a `key` property - a "prefix" for the css classes, as the documenation says. I figure it's there to allow multiple caches in multiple namespaces, but I wouldn't even know how to specify the `key`/namespace to be used.

If anybody could shed some light on (some) of these questions, I'm grateful!

Comment: In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799638/material-ui-textfield-not-affected-with-the-rtl-direction/62802353#62802353) (in the v5 example further down in the answer) you can see an example of using two different caches with the CacheProvider.

Comment: `StyledEngineProvider` is a MUI component for providing configurations to the styling engine (Emotion or styled-components) in a styling-engine-neutral fashion. `injectFirst` is the only property it supports and it is equivalent to using `prepend: true` for the cache passed to `CacheProvider`, but `CacheProvider` is Emotion-specific.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for your responses! So the different cache `keys` aren't used to pick one cache, but just the `value` property passed to the `CacheProvider`? Regarding the `StyledEngineProvider`: I guess I don't really get what a `StyleEngine` is at all. The `ThemeProvider` is there to propagate the `Palette` to different components. But what's the purpose of a `StyleEngine`?