# How to set mui textfield for hebrew?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use mui textfield for hebrew. The code looks like

```
<TextField
   label={isEnglish ? "Name" : "שם"}
   variant="outlined"
   className={"w-[300px]"}
   dir={isEnglish ? "ltr" : "rtl"}
   lang={isEnglish ? "en" : "he"}
/>
```

But the label isn't placed in right. How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question ?? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62799638/11399221

Comment: try too  add   InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
   }}

Comment: @Arman perfectly works